# access variable outside a class

Tags: php, oop

I want to try accessing an outside variable from a class object.
how can it be possible?

my code:

```
<?php 
  $variable = "vikrant";
  class greet {
     public function __construct($name){
        echo "hello - {$name}--{$variable}";
     }
  }
  $message = new greet("vijay");
  

?>
```

this thing doesn't work. but I need to know how to achieve it.

Comment: Pass it into the constructor like you do with the other value. But don't use hacks like using globals.

Answer (score -1):

Use php superglobal `$GLOBALS`. $GLOBALS - References all variables available in global scope.

```
$variable = "vikrant";
class greet {
  public function __construct($name){
     echo "hello - {$name}--{$GLOBALS['variable']}";
  }
}
$message = new greet("vijay");//hello - vijay--vikrant
```

[$GLOBALS](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)